# Use copr with rpmfusion-nonfree packages

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm building a custom `ffmpeg` with `fdk-aac-devel`. This dependency is located in `rpmfusing-nonfree`. So copr build fails because it cannot find this package. Is there a way for me to install this dependency in a copr build?

The current best solution I can think of is to download the dependency SRPM and build it on copr. But I don't really know how to include this copr-built dependency in another copr build. If you know how to use a prebuilt *binary* package as dependency, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the chroot in your COPR settings,   and add the repository URL to be included when building the chroot. However, I suspect including those packages would be including [forbidden items](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Forbidden_items), which are not allowed according to the [COPR documentation](https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#what-i-can-build-in-copr)

Comment: Do you have detailed instructions that others can follow line by line? I haven't fully read the text you link, but I found the fdk aac license is listed as a *Good* one, so I think it's OK to build it on copr.

Comment: Go to your projects settings. When you enable a chroot, an Edit button appears. Click it. In the Edit page, there is a text area called Repos. You can add the yum repo there. It’s just the URL of the repo.

Comment: jsbillings is right, you cannot build in Copr anything related to rpmfusion. Nothing which either BuilRequires or Requires something from rpmfusion. I am saying that with my Copr-admin hat on.

Comment: @msuchy That confused me. First of all, rpmfusion has both free and non-free variants. Why would rpmfusion-free packages be excluded on Copr? Second, even packages in rpmfusion-nonfree may have a license that is explicitly considered to be *Good* in the official Copr documentation. Search for *FDK-AAC* in this list: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing:Main?rd=Licensing#Good_Licenses The fedora license page also calls it free: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing/FDK-AAC

Comment: Thank you so much bro. It turned out to be even simpler: Copr already got it in mind that people might need another repo as dependency. So one can simply use `copr://{user}/{project}` instead of the full base url in the external dependency list. This is amazing.

Comment: @Cyker: See https://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#Free_repository The reason is mostly: patents.

Comment: @msuchy Well, not being accepted in fedora repos isn't the same thing as being excluded from copr builds. I didn't see copr documentation mentions anywhere about rpmfusion. The copr documentation only talks about licenses, not those "various reasons". Specifically, I still don't see how `fdk-aac` would violate the copr terms.

Comment: @Cyker https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#what-i-can-build-in-copr item c -- is categorized as a “Forbidden Item” at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Forbidden_items, as that page may be revised from time to time by the Fedora Council; If you disagree than please raise this with Fedora legal. I would be happy to soften the term. I even tried. But it is hard and exhausting to work with lawyers.

Comment: @msuchy No, that *forbidden items* page doesn't mention `fdk-aac` at all. And if you go to [its wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC), you will see *It was classified as free by Fedora after a review by the legal department at Red Hat.* [Another evidence](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing/FDK-AAC): *It is free.*

Comment: @cyker You are right https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/F64JBJI2IZFT2A5QDXGHNMPALCQIVJAX/ sorry.